# Overnight layover in New York airports

Tags: air-travel, new-york-city, layovers, jfk

I have a flight with Iberia from Spain coming into JFK (New York - JF Kennedy) Terminal 7 at 9:15pm, and because of a change of plans I need to book a flight to Atlanta from there. However, there are no such flights departing after that.

If I book a Delta flight from T4 for the following morning, could I just check my bag all the way to Atlanta from origin, and go into the airside of Terminal 4 at around 11:30pm?

If that's not possible I could also transfer to LGA (New York - La Guardia) and fly to Atlanta from there the next morning. Which airport's landside area is best for a layover?

Will airport security have a problem with a 17-year-old sleeping there overnight?

Comment: What airline is your flight from Spain with?

Comment: It's an Iberia flight

Comment: The quality of JFK is very terminal-dependent, but http://www.sleepinginairports.net/ may be a help.

Comment: For the first part, I think the answer is no. Iberia and Delta are in different alliances, so are unlikely to through-check across two different tickets. Iberia to American would work though, as those two are both OneWorld

Comment: @choster: When I overstayed the night in Terminal 1, I could not find any place/lounge to rest. Granted, I didn't do my research before, and there may be possible options.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly stay at the airport airside or landside as long as you have your belongings and boarding pass available for inspection.  This topic has been discussed on [Flyer Talk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/new-york-city/945988-what-do-overnight-layover-jfk-consolidated.html) before.

Personally the comfort level in both LaGuardia and JFK overnight is about the same for my liking but I'd just stay put just so I don't have to pay for the cab or a bus.